# display value in UIlabel from CLLocation manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

i have the following code, which is going to form the backbone of a GPS app.

I am trying to get the location (lat & long) and speed, and display their value in a label.

Here is my Code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longditute = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        Latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

         NSString *gpsSpeed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f",newLocation.speed];

        speedLable.text= gpsSpeed;
        latitudeLable.text = Latitude;
        LongitudeLabel.text = longditute;



    }

}
```

to my mind, i should see the values printed in the labels, but there never seems to be any changes. they just show the default "label" text. Can anybody suggest where I've gone wrong, and how to fix it?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to post code, so I'm using a new answer rather than a following comment to @user2766755 's answer.

The parameter oldLocation is no longer sent in the new method. You weren't using oldLocation, so you shouldn't need it.

Additionally, instead of getting a single location, newLocation, you now get an NSArray of new locations. Use the NSArray method lastObject to get the most recent location object from the array.

To get the most recent location in a variable newLocation you could use code like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager 
  didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *) locations
{
  CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
  //The rest of your code goes here...
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes, yet the labels still aren't updating.

Comment: The next obvious question is: Is the delegate method even being called?  If your running on simulator you might need to simulate location debug -> location (or simulate location depending on simulator or Xcode).  If it's not then check to see if it's authorized.  If it's still not I suspect your CLLocationManager instance is being dealloced and if that's the case then declare a property for it.

Comment: Add a log statement to make sure your delegate method is being called. Then check to make sure the outlets aren't nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the wrong delegate method to receive the location update.  You should implement

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

The one you are using was deprecated in iOS6.

Comment: thanks for that. Im now getting use of undeclared identifiers errors associated with my use of the variables "oldLocation" and "new"Location". how do i now declare these variables?

Comment: All the locations are in the locations array.  The most recent location will be locations.lastObject.  Please read the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/cllocationmanagerdelegate_protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations: